# Non-parametric test for proportions data

Tags: nonparametric, proportion

I am analyzing some behavioral footage and am not sure what an appropriate non-parametric test would be for proportion data? Specifically, I'm looking at visit durations at a feeding station and the proportion of time spent

1. foraging or
2. vigilant of the total visit time.

The foraging proportions are in the realm of 0.5-0.9, whereas the vigilance proportions are closer to 0-0.5. I want to test the differences before and after the addition of an odour treatment.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why use a nonparametric test?

Comment: These are continuous proportions. Can you give some more details, such as sample size.  Look into use a generalized linear model, or maybe a beta regression.

Comment: I sense a potential misconception (caused by a common error in many elementary books) -- that of conflating the quite distinct concepts of *nonparametric* and *non-normal*, because of the corresponding misconception that the only parametric model is a normal one. There are common parametric tests that are used when responses are (conditionally) modelled using some distribution other than the normal (kjetil was discussing some potentially suitable parametric models in their comment).  There may be a nonparametric test you can use but don't be too quick to dismiss parametric tests out of hand.

Comment: Hi all. Sample sizes are as followed:

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments! Sample sizes are as followed: control (n=81), treatment 1 (n=21), treatment 2 (n=16) and treatment 3 (n=30). I thought that based on the small sample sizes and non-normality of my data, non-parametric was necessary. I've never dealt with proportions before, and while I know about the two-proportions z-test, this isn't appropriate in this case. So I wasn't sure if I should be log transforming the proportions and using Wilcoxon/K-W tests or whether I need to use a GLM with binomial or beta distribution..